# Graph REST API - Get User Messages - Permission Required

Tags: azure, permissions, microsoft-graph-api

It's a Microsoft 365 environment.

Similar to [Graph API permission for non-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73233768/graph-api-permission-for-non-admin/77255135?noredirect=1#comment136195758_77255135)

User1 (user1@contoso.com) has full access rights to the shared mailbox (sharedmailbox@contoso.com), which includes an 'Intake' folder within the 'Inbox.' This can be verified throug Outlook Email Client.

In the Graph Explorer Enterprise Application.I've granted User1 Delegated Mail.ReadWrite permissions at user consent.
Also has the Delegated Mail.ReadWrite permissions at Admin consent.

User1 can log in to Graph Explorer and successfully access its own mailbox using the following API endpoint:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders (OK - 200)
However, when attempting to access the 'Intake' folder within the shared mailbox using the following API endpoint:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/sharedmailbox@contoso.com/mailFolders
It results in a 'Forbidden - 403' error. The error message suggests that either the signed-in user does not have sufficient privileges or that additional permissions need to be granted, possibly on the 'Modify permissions' tab.

I have also tried building an application and granting it Mail.ReadWrite permission. While this works for accessing all users mailboxes, it is not the desired behavior as we only want it to access the 'sharedmailbox@contoso.com' mailbox.

How can I access the 'Intake' folder through the Graph API while logged in as User1?

Thanks in advance.

Add:
I tried using Python
Get 200 and 403 too

```py
import requests

# Define the base API URL, API version, and endpoint
base_api = 'https://graph.microsoft.com'
api_version = 'v1.0'
endpoint_me = '/me/mailFolders'
endpoint_sharedmailbox = '/users/sharedmailbox@contoso.com/mailFolders'


# Define the access token
# Access token get from when User1 login
token = 'TOKEN'

# Construct the URL
url_me = f'{base_api}/{api_version}{endpoint_me}'
url_sharedmailbox = f'{base_api}/{api_version}{endpoint_sharedmailbox}'

# Define the headers with access token
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

# Make a GET request to Graph API
response_me = requests.get(url_me, headers=headers)
response_sharedmailbox = requests.get(url_sharedmailbox, headers=headers)
print(response_me.status_code)
print(response_sharedmailbox.status_code)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the permission required for shared mailboxes is Mail.Read.Shared

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-share-messages-folders
https://graphpermissions.merill.net/permission/Mail.Read.Shared